# Application in Market that Open click returns you back to the market

Tags: google-play-store, asus-eee-pad-transformer, uninstallation

I had NetFlix installed on ASUS Eee Transformer and since I am not using it, I uninstalled it.

But now Android Market tells me there are updates, which I do not wish to do, and it acts as though it is still installed. Ok, I went to open it to see the app, and Open just takes me back to the Android Market page.

I see the same behavior on Mobo Video player. I installed it, it said to go get the codecs, so I did, then when I open it, I get sent back to the Android Market page.  Tried uninstalling, same basic behavior.

How do I clean these up?  They seem to be in some kind of installed/uninstalled limbo.

Running the latest update from ASUS, so Android 3.2.1 and latest firmware.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like ASUS has installed stubs as system apps.  You'd need root to remove them or unlink them from the Market.

Comment: I can buy that for the Netflix app, and I can probably live with that one.  The Mobo Player one is a bit annoying.  I seem to missing something obvious about this one.

Answer (score 2):

I wonder if you uninstalled via some method other than the market and things got out of sync? Settings / Manage Applications or a launcher shortcut, for instance.

I would suggest re-installing both apps, then uninstalling via their market pages.

Comment: I used Market for both.  Though maybe Netflix, now I do not recall...  Hmm... Something to think about, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Can you once try by clearing the "Market" and "Download Manager" cache and data?

To do so go to Settings -> Manage Applications -> Select "Market" from "All" tab and click clear cache and clear data.

Do the same for "Download Manager"

Comment: No joy, same behavior on both problem apps.

Answer (score -1):

You need a cache clean up apps to get rid of all those nasty hanging apps. There you will find that your cache has alot in it. Cleaning it once a day helps with performance also so try to make it a habbit of cleaning it once a day!!

Comment: He already tried it to no avail. Also please don't spread false information that cleaning cache speeds up your phone. It doesn't.